# what is making my logitech LUA code not work?

Tags: lua, logitech

ive recently had some help fixing my Logitech autoclicker script to remove the errors in the code and now logitech ghub seems to think the code is functional, except every time i try to use it the most i get is one click out of it instead of 1 click every 20-80ms while im holding left click.
thanks in advance to anyone that is able to help

code is as follows:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            repeat
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
                        Sleep(math.random(20,60))
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: what happens if you release mousebutton 1 and click it again while holding mouse button 3 down?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works exactly how it is written; in that as long as caps lock is enabled, the right mouse button is being held and the left mouse is being held it will continue to click with your random interval wait periods. However, the reason why it's only clicking once is because the "Press And RELEASE" is being called meaning that left mouse button is no longer being held after that call which breaks your repeat loop. Try just doing if the right mouse button is held and it works fine.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
            repeat
              PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
              Sleep(math.random(20,60))
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not simulate LMB press and listen for its state simultaneously.
The simplest solution is to assign another key for fire ingame instead of LMB.
I assume you have assigned <kbd>P</kbd> key for shooting.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") and IsMouseButtonPressed(3) then
         repeat
            PressKey("P")
            Sleep(math.random(20,60))
            ReleaseKey("P")
            Sleep(math.random(20,60))
         until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
      end
   end
end
```